# General technique to check the convergence of an improper integral?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

[Which of these integrals converge ?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i7Nr4.jpg)

I am confused about how to check for the convergence when the functions are more complex inside the integral.

My attempt:

in option C : integrating gives -2 and hence should converge i guess.
in option D: its sin inverse (x) and the upper limit 2 actually cant be applied right ?
option a and option b i am pretty much clueless on how to even start with?!

Comment: c) diverges. You integrate over a singularity, and must take care of that one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a) converge  $\int=2$.

b) converge  because $-1\le \sin(x) \le 1$ so $\int \le \int_1^\infty \frac1{x^3}dx$ which converge.

c) not converge : 0 is a singularity of $1/x^2$ and is in the integration interval. and the two integrals $\int_{-1}^0$ , $\int_0^1$ are not converging.

d) 1 which is a singularity of $f(x)=\frac1{\sqrt{|1-x^2|}}$. But, the two integrals \int_0^1 f(x) dx and $\int_1^2 f(x) dx are converging. So the integral converge.

the primitive of $\frac1{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$ is $\arcsin(x)$ ,and of $\frac1{\sqrt{x^2-1}}$ is $\operatorname{arcsinh}(x)$.

Comment: i didnt understand your explanation of option D/ ?

Comment: $\int_0^2 f(x) dx = \int_0^1 \frac1{\sqrt{1-x^2}} dx + \int_1^2 \frac1{\sqrt{x^2-1}} dx$.The difference with the case c) is that the integral in c) $\int_{-1}^0$ is not converging and $\int_{0}^1$ is not converging.